# How to troubleshoot sql server performance problem

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

Ok this general problem has reared its ugly head twice in the past 6 months (different stored procedure). We have our internal users report a timeout error in the application. We can reproduce the problem in the application in a controlled environment. So we go through the normal steps of checking for blocking using sp_who2. Everything looks good with no blocking. So we do a sql trace to see exactly how the procedure is being executed. We copy that to a new window in SQL Management Studio and execute what sql trace was telling us ADO.Net was doing it and it finished in milliseconds. Our applications timeout is 30 seconds. When this problem happened a couple months back we had SQL Server 2005. We now have upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2. Whats the next step to diagnose a problem like this?

@Martin: Thanks for the response. I will read your post in detail and let you know what i found out. Until then here is the sql in the SP you requested:

```
Select 
    @Exists=0, 
    @EarnRecId=0,
    @SuppStatusId = 0,
    @SLRecId = 0,
    @EarnRecDS = Null

Select
    @EarnRecId = er.EarningsId,
    @EarnRecDS = Convert(Varchar(26),er.Datestamp, 109),
    @SuppStatusId = s.SuppStatusId,
    @SLRecId = s.SLId
From
    Tracking tr
    Inner Join Supps s On s.SuppId = tr.SuppId
    Inner Join Earnings er On er.EarnRecId = s.SuppId
Where
    tr.ClaimId = @ClaimId
    and er.FiscalYr = @FiscalYr
    And er.EmplyrId In (@EmpId1,@EmpId2)

If @EarnRecId > 0
    Begin
        Set @Exists=1
    End
```

Comment: Indexes or statistics are the problem. The query plan from ADO is different to the query plan directly on the server for some reason. So check your indexes and statistics.

Comment: Why would there be a difference on how ado.net and sql management studio executes the same exact stored procedure? To try to alleviate the problem just update stats & defrag indexes?

Comment: @user - There wouldn't be. Of course both invocations would be using the same statistics and indexes so if that is the cause of the problem it should occur for both. It is almost certainly parameter sniffing. DON'T rebuild your indexes/statistics now! That will cause the plan to be dropped from the cache and foil any attempts to confirm this. Can you post the query?

Comment: I would suggest trying the following. (1) Determine your least common and most common ClaimId, FiscalYr, and EmplyrId values. (2) Substitute the least common ones into one version of the select query as constants (3) Do the same with the most common ones. (4) Compare the execution plans. By the way I was a bit unsure about where the assignment to scalar variables leaves my theory. Is the result only ever guaranteed to return one row if you were to remove the assignment?

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this, but you can use SQL profiler to view the event's execution plan. That can help determine if issue is parameter sniffing as Martin suggested.
Details here: http://tinyurl.com/2xccjm

Answer (score 4):

Probably parameter sniffing.

When the stored procedure is invoked and there is no existing execution plan in the cache matching the `set` options for the connection a new execution plan will be compiled using the parameter values passed in on that invocation.

Sometimes this will happen when the parameters passed are atypical (e.g. have unusually high selectivity) so the generated plan will not be suitable for most other invocations with different parameters.

SSMS has a different default value for the option `SET ARITH_ABORT` so will not get handed the same problematic plan when you execute the stored procedure inside SSMS.

Next time it happens possibly the simplest way of investigating the issue would be to have 2 separate SSMS windows with the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option enabled and in one do

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
EXEC YourProc ...
```

And in the other

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
EXEC YourProc ...
```

Assuming default ADO.NET and SSMS connection options the first one should use the bad plan from the cache.

If that doesn't work for you you could use profiler to see what other set options you need to fiddle with to get the bad plan or just use profiler to get the execution plans directly - or you can retrieve them from the DMVs as below.

```
select p.query_plan, *
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) p
where r.session_id = <spid of your ADO.NET connection>
```

You might find that the problematic plan is doing tens of thousands of individual index seeks for example whereas the good plan avoids this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a solution but i don't like it. The SP that has the issue is exec twice in succession. The only parameter that changes during the call above is @FiscalYr. The first call is 20102011 while the next call (the slow one) is 20092010. The first call is fast. I finally set the CommandTimeout = 0 so i could tell how long the call takes and it was over 3 minutes. I don't understand why because both inner joins in each case returns 1 record so the qry plans should be identical. If the first call returned 1 record & the 2nd call returned 10000 records i cld maybe understand

Comment: anyways the solution is to put "with recompile" on the SP which i absolutely hate because its more of a hack then a solution. I don't like to put anything like that or join hints into procedures. Oh btw, its also interesting to note that after i increased the timeout and let both run and if i try to try to run them both again...both are fast until i do a "dbcc freeproccache"

Comment: You could use `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@FiscalYr UNKNOWN))` can you get the actual execution plan for the slow running invocation? If so there should be something obvious there.

Comment: ...By which I mean that you may find it is doing a lot more work than you are expecting and that there is significantly more than one row being returned by the join. Feel free to post the actual execution XML plan in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Martin is totally right. But I'll add my 2 cents to summarize:

1. Obviously, **SSMS and  your app use different execution plans**
2. **Why?** Because your app uses a cached plan and SSMS, by default, tells the server to always create a new plan.
3. Fast and dirty solution - **clear the cache**

Run this

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Helps 90% of the time.

PS. (IMO) Say, you rebooted your server. The server is still busy starting things up etc, but your web app already starts getting http requests form users! So your poor little SQL starts creating and caching execution plans... While doing a ton of other things at the same time! That's why the execution plans are far from optimal after rebooting a busy machine...