# MS SQL Timeout on ASP.NET Page but not in SSMS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception, stored-procedures, timeout

When a sproc is executed on one of our ASP.NET pages, it times out on the SQL Server with the exception `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`. When I execute the same sproc in SSMS, it returns relatively quickly. The SQL Server and IIS are on the same box. I logged in as the same user in both places. Other pages are just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably Parameter Sniffing.

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478839/how-to-troubleshoot-sql-server-performance-problem/3479113#3479113) gives you some queries that you can use to retrieve both execution plans (the SSMS one and the ASP.NET one) to compare and contrast.

**Edit**

This might be a more useful query actually.

```
Use YourDatabase;

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) 
cross APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle) AS epa
where sys.dm_exec_sql_text.OBJECTID=object_id('YourProcName') 
         and attribute='set_options'
```

Comment: I saw no (noticeable) difference in the execution plan. However, now my sproc works on the ASP.NET page... Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel - Maybe the stored procedure got recompiled (this can happen for a variety of reasons - e.g. if you run `ALTER` on its definition or if any of the statistics it is dependant on get updated). If not then maybe it was not a parameter sniffing issue at all. I guess you'll not find out for sure unless it happens again.

Comment: Thanks Martin for letting me know about this strangeness.

Answer (score 1):

1) The default timeout for an ADO.Net command to SQL Server is 30 seconds. You can change this to a higher value (or 0 to disable timeouts) on the SqlCOmmand object. SSMS doesn't have a timeout when it runs queries.

2) But it may be that the query is timing out because something else is blocking it from running. Whilst waiting for a response from the asp.net page, are you able to run sp_who2 on the SQL Server, and check the Blk column - if there's an entry there with a value different to the SPID in the same row, some blocking is occurring.

Answer (score -2):

Try increasing the [`CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(VS.71).aspx) property and see if that resolves the issue:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.CommandTimeout = 150;
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```